# Decimate modifier with tileable meshes

Tags: modifiers, polycount, height-map

I'm looking for a solution to decimate the vertex count and keep my mesh tileable.
I've made some textures in substance and now I want to generate a mesh out of the heightmap - so I created a plane, did some loop cuts, a subdivision surface modifier and a displacement modifier with the heightmap and I increased the SS-modifier till it looked good. Then I applied both mods and used the decimate modifier - it works extremely well. But the problem are the edges of the plane - of course, the geometry on the edges decimates different - so i get small cracks when I want to tile them.

My current workaround is to use the decimate modifier two times -> the first time only a little bit, so there are no cracks, and the second time with a vertex group selected, which excludes the outer edges. The result is ok, but I don't really need all this vertices on the edges.
Does someone have a better idea how to solve this?
The best thing would be to keep the opposite edges of the plane symmetrized while decimating.

Thank you very much!

[image: Vertices edges]

[image: Vertex count right]

[image: Vertex count left]

Comment: Hello, could you add some screenshots so we visualize the problem and the expected behaviour ? If I understand correctly, you could add the edge vertices in a vertex group and then specify this vertex group in the decimate modifier with the 'invert' mode so that the decimate modifier doesn't touch these vertices.

Comment: Hi Gorgious.
Thank you for the answer.
Yes, I used the vertex group in the decimate modifier - the problem is that there are too many vertices on the edges then. I'm basically looking for a solution to decimate the vertices on the edges and keep the symmetry at the same time.
I'll add screenshots to the question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today. The way i solved it, was to just do the 1 decimate at the amount of detail your happy with, use either x or y symmetry to make life a bit easier. Then use Linked Duplicates to put a tile on the top, bottom left and right. Then you go around the outside edge of the middle tile and adjust each vert with either vertex snapping, or edge snapping so that you end up with a seamless 3d Tile.